#  Storing the comment data from post view in yii

Tags: php, yii

i can get the form of comment in the post by the following code..

```
<?php $comment= new Comment();
        $this->renderPartial('/comment/_form',array('model'=>$comment,)); 
?>
```

but now it is require that the  data fill in the comment form of post view is store in the database. 
Another problem, when fill data in the comment form of create new comment it creates 2 similar record in the databse.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/comment.create check this

Comment: post here the code of your action to analysis

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not very clearly explained, but form what I understand, you should try looking in to CFormModel and its validators.

Let me know if you would like to discuss details.